# Changing footer position to be at the bottom of page until it hits content

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

(I am looking for an HTML/CSS fix but if there really is none then JS (prefereably JQuery) works for me)

I have two main divs inside my page, I have the #maincontent and the #footer.

Basically, I want the footer to always sit at the bottom on the page:

```
#footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

BUT I do not want it to overflow on the #maincontent when the page is too small.
For the sake of the question the page can be thought of as simple as:

```
<body>
<div id="maincontent">Dynamic Content</div>
<div id="footer">StaticContent</div>
</body>
```

My problem is that I can do one or the other, either I fix it to the bottom of the page but when I make the viewport < (footer + maincontent) the footer sits on top of the content. I want the footer to always be at the bottom of the page but disappear off page before it overtakes the main content.

Comment: position: absolute; bottom: 0;

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

If you know your footer's height whatever happens to the window height, or its content :

- Just add a "padding-bottom" to your body or main content that matches the footer's height.

If you don't know your footer's height. This is trickier, as you will probably need some javascript to calculate the height of the footer, the height of the main content, compare the sum of both with the window height, and if it doesn't fit, add some adequate bottom padding to the body / main content.

EDIT :

Ok I understand, I think this jsfiddle should do the trick : http://jsfiddle.net/ah4XA/2/

The javascript would be :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function updateFooter () {
    var footerH = $("#main-footer").height();
    var contentH = $("#main-content").height();
    var windowH = $(window).height();
    if ( contentH + footerH > windowH) {
        $("#main-footer").removeClass("fixed");
    } else {
        $("#main-footer").addClass("fixed");
    }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    updateFooter();
});

updateFooter();
});
```

Comment: No this doesnt work, I want it to always hug the (bottom:0) however dissappear when you scroll to much (as in never let the footer go over the content. I am finding it quite tricky to articulate. But to confirm your question, yes, my footer will always be 70px, it is only ever the content that is dynamic.

Comment: All right, made some edits to my original answer, that may be the solution. May that do the trick, please, use debouncedresize.js

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the footer with jQuery that changes it to `position: absolute` when the viewport is too small.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var height = $(window).height();

    function windowHeight() {
        height = $(window).height();
    }

    windowHeight();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        windowHeight();
    });

    if (height < 600) { //arbitrary height value you can set yourself
        $('#footer').addClass('not-fixed');
    } else {
        $('#footer').removeClass('not-fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for, you want the footer to stay on the bottom of the window regardless of the page content, but also not overlap the page as the window is resized vertically.

One possible solution is to switch between `position:absolute;` and `position: fixed;` with a media query. So past a certain height it's fixed, but below that the footer `position:absolute;`.

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/tL3cR/)**

CSS:

```
@media all and (max-height:300px) {
  #footer {
    background: red; <- added for testing
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

The only drawback to this approach is that you need to know the height to set the switchover to. This may be tricky, but `position:fixed;`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to position footer at the bottom permanently and increase the `z-index` of your `maincontent` so that it comes over the footer if window size is decreased.

NOTE: This is not the only way to do this.

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/q88ST/)

**Sample CSS**

```
#maincontent{
    height : 400px;
    background-color : green;
    /*
        position : relative is added to enable z-index.
    */
    position:relative;
    /*
        z-index will bring it above footer,
        if window size is reduced.
    */
    z-index: 1;
    width : 100%;
}
#footer{
    height : 100px;
    width : 100%;
    background-color : black;
    /*    Below two properties will 
          postion footer at the bottom of the page.
    */
    position : fixed;
    bottom : 0;
    color : white;
}
```

You should [play](http://web-dev-lover.blogspot.in/2014/01/css-position-property.html) with CSS `position` property to get this done.

**EDIT:**

Here is another CSS solution :

The `maincontent` and `footer` are wrapped in a `bodyContainer` div its position is set to relative and then footer is positioned w.r.t it.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/q88ST/1/)** Footer is below body and not shown.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/q88ST/2/)** Footer is shown since body height is less.

**HTML**

```
<div id="bodyContainer">
    <div id="maincontent">Dynamic Content
    </div>
    <div id="footer">StaticContent</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bodyContainer {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#maincontent{
    height : 800px;
    background-color : green;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    width : 100%;
}
#footer{
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Because of the make up of the content this wouldn't work for me, well asethetically it wouldn't. I am so surprised that there isnt a non JS way.. .thank you though... JS it is for me then!

Comment: @Phish I have updated answer with another solution, check if it serves your purpose.